# AWS CDK: Api Gateway endpoints fail to generate

Tags: amazon-web-services

After running `cdk bootstrap && cdk synth && cdk deploy` I am not getting an endpoint url in terminal. I also do not see the new endpoint in the Api Gateway web console.

This is what I see at the deploy stage:

```
Do you wish to deploy these changes (y/n)? y
StackName: deploying...
[0%] start: Publishing 00c90632b9fd2c6<removed>:current
[100%] success: Published 00c90632b9fd2c<removed>:current
StackName: creating CloudFormation changeset...
[█████████████████████████████████████] (4/4)

 ✅  StackName

Stack ARN:
arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:939<removed>
```

This is inside my top level construct, am I missing something else needed to generate the api gateway (and/or lambda handler)?

```
const lambdaHandler = new lambda.Function(this, 'LambdaHandler', {
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, "lambda")),
      handler: 'test.func1',
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X
    });

const lpIntegration = new apiGatewayV2.LambdaProxyIntegration({
  handler: lambdaHandler
});

const api = new apiGatewayV2.HttpApi(this, "httpApi", {
  corsPreflight: {
    allowHeaders: ['Authorization'],
    allowMethods: [apiGatewayV2.HttpMethod.GET, apiGatewayV2.HttpMethod.HEAD, apiGatewayV2.HttpMethod.OPTIONS, apiGatewayV2.HttpMethod.POST],
    allowOrigins: ['*'],
  },
});

api.addRoutes({
  path: '/testEndpoint',
  methods: [apiGatewayV2.HttpMethod.ANY],
  integration: lpIntegration
})


// package.json deps
"devDependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/assert": "1.55.0",
    "jest": "^25.5.0",
    "ts-jest": "^25.3.1",
    "aws-cdk": "1.55.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2": "^1.55.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "^1.55.0",
    "@aws-cdk/core": "1.55.0",
```

**Update**

I ran `aws configure` again and confirmed my region to be us-east-2. The web console also shows information (including API Gateways) in this region.

I am including my latest CloudFormation logs from the web console below.

```
2020-07-31 03:14:50 UTC+0700    StackName   UPDATE_COMPLETE -
2020-07-31 03:14:49 UTC+0700    StackName   UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS -
2020-07-31 03:14:47 UTC+0700    LambdaHandlerStackNamehttpApiANYtestEndpoint98A4C450PermissionE8E46AF9  CREATE_COMPLETE -
2020-07-31 03:14:42 UTC+0700    httpApiANYtestEndpoint2F5D131D  CREATE_COMPLETE -
2020-07-31 03:14:42 UTC+0700    httpApiANYtestEndpoint2F5D131D  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2020-07-31 03:14:41 UTC+0700    httpApiANYtestEndpoint2F5D131D  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2020-07-31 03:14:38 UTC+0700    httpApiANYtestEndpointANYtestEndpointIntegration533B29D7    CREATE_COMPLETE -
2020-07-31 03:14:38 UTC+0700    httpApiANYtestEndpointANYtestEndpointIntegration533B29D7    CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2020-07-31 03:14:37 UTC+0700    LambdaHandlerStackNamehttpApiANYtestEndpoint98A4C450PermissionE8E46AF9  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2020-07-31 03:14:37 UTC+0700    httpApiANYtestEndpointANYtestEndpointIntegration533B29D7    CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2020-07-31 03:14:37 UTC+0700    LambdaHandlerStackNamehttpApiANYtestEndpoint98A4C450PermissionE8E46AF9  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2020-07-31 03:14:08 UTC+0700    StackName   UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated
```

Comment: You can go to CloudFormation console, and inspect there if the stack and the api got deployed. Maybe you check in different region?

Comment: @Marcin thanks, I confirmed the region is the same. i also posted the latest cloudformation logs above

Comment: It seems to be created. You can go again to CloudFormation console, go to this stack, and check Resources tab to check for api.

Comment: @Marcin Ok, I have navigated to `Resources` and clicked the link to the API resource. The API Gateway web console opens and a red popper flashes saying `Invalid Api identifier specified {medium length string of characters}`. I will proceed to get a developer plan and open a ticket as this may be a bug on the CDK or CloudFormation side.

Comment: I am not sure, but try to give a different ID than 'httpApi'